# Databricks Community Edition Clusters won't start - Getting BootStrap Time Error

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

Can someoneo from the Databricks Community let me know if there currently issues with the Databricks Community Edition. After waiting over 45mins for the cluster to start the cluster fails to start and gives the following error:

```
BootStrap Timeout:
Node daemon ping timeout in 780000 ms for instance i-037a1c9eea2a4bc7f @ 10.172.200.141. Please check network connectivity between the data plane and the control plane.
```

Can someone let me know if this is an international or national problem.

The cluster was starting fine earlier with no issues.

Comment: It is a known and relatively recent issue apparently and a fix is allegedly "on the way" : https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/bootstrap-timeout-during-cluster-start/td-p/18976
But community clusters are known to unreliable. Paid plans backed by public cloud do not have this issue to my knowledge